# How to create a chatbot based on input length in python

Tags: python

I have inputs below

```
inputs=["Hi","I want to know some information about the course"]
```

I have responses here

```
responses=["Hi,How can I help you?","Which course do you want to take?"]
```

I want to create a chatbot based on input length it should give corresponding response i.e, if user enters `"Hi"`,It has to compare length and word in inputs list and give corresponding response from responses list.
I tried like below

```
### splitting list elements as words
user_word_split=[word for line in inputs for word in str(line).split()]
### Asking user for enter their text
while True:
    user=input('User:')
#### seeing if user text present in the existing list
    for i in range(0,len(user_word_split)):
        commonElements=[x for x in (user_word_split) if x in user]
#### comparing the length of the inputs and giving responses if condition meets.    
    if len(user)>=len(commonElements):
        user=input(responses[0])
    elif len(user)>=len(commonElements):
        user=input(responses[1])
```

Output:

```
User:Hi
chatbot: Hi,How can i help you?
```

It is giving response even i enter `"go"` as user text.It is not comparing word exists in input list.It is only comparing length.How can i achieve that.If `user text length >= len(commonElements)` It has to get first response from responses list and so on.But I am getting only first response from responses list every time irrespective of the word comparision.

Expected output:

```
User: Hi
chatbot: Hi,How can I help you?
User: I want to know some information aout the course
chatbot: Which course do you want to take?
```

Comment: `if len(user)>=len(commonElements):
        user=input(responses[0])
    elif len(user)>=len(commonElements):
        user=input(responses[1])` both things are same ,

Comment: Condition is same but user text is different.It has give response by comparing word and length of that word in a input list.

Comment: It has to take intersection of words present in inputs list(existing) and user text.

Comment: it will always follow the first one as `len(user)>= len(commonElements)` this fact not change, you need to add `else` also where you put `user=input(responses[1])`

Comment: I am getting first response every time with else condition

Comment: @Maggie , check this [link](https://ideone.com/OFRRsj) it wil help you, if you creating a chat bot dont do it this way try this for [learning](https://towardsdatascience.com/build-your-first-chatbot-using-python-nltk-5d07b027e727)

Comment: Getting errors with the link code.Requirement is to create chatbot with if else conditions only.That's why i tried like above.

Comment: [see this](https://github.com/parulnith/Building-a-Simple-Chatbot-in-Python-using-NLTK) this will help you on chatbot, in above one condition of text is not good in chatbot  follow this link tutorial and see how a chatbot is created simple